# SQL Server Substring with CharIndex used on nested XML tags

Tags: sql-server, xml, stored-procedures, substring

This is the stored procedure I'm using to get 5 digits from an xml:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_KINGPRICE_InsertJournalFromPost]
    (
        @ResponseID bigint,
        @TransactionDetailID bigint
    )
    AS
    BEGIN
    DECLARE @info as varchar(max) = '', @Reference as varchar(max) = ''
    SET @info = (SELECT SUBSTRING(Response, CHARINDEX('<GlJournal>',Response) + 11,5) 
                 FROM SysproIntegration..ifmTransactionDetailResponse 
                 WHERE TransactionDetailResponseID = @ResponseID)
    SET @Reference = (SELECT DISTINCT Reference 
                      FROM GenJournalDetail 
                      WHERE Journal = CAST(@info as DECIMAL(5,0)))
    INSERT INTO ZJournalRecords
    (JournalNumber,Reference)

    VALUES (@info,@Reference)
    END
```

The XML has a tag like this:

```
    <GLJournal>12345</GLJournal>
```

If the XML document has only one of these tags, I have no worries. The SP works fine. The problem comes in when there are two nested `<GLJournal>` tags. The xml would then look something like:

```
    <GLJournal>
        <SomeTag/>
        <SomeTag2/>
        <GLJournal>12345</GLJournal>
    </GLJournal>
```

How can I get the 5 digit value of the nested tag? (It will always be 5 digits)
I have thought of using a try catch, but that doesn't seem like an elegant solution.

EDIT:
Also, part of the problem is, I don't know when there will be one `GlJournal` tags, or two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to count the number of occurrences of the tag, and based on that, substring a certain position.

```
DECLARE @info as varchar(max) = '', @Reference as varchar(max) = '', @inputString as varchar(max), @searchString as varchar(max), @numberOfTags as int

SET @searchString = '<GlJournal>'
SET @inputString = (SELECT Response FROM SysproIntegration..ifmTransactionDetailResponse WHERE TransactionDetailResponseID = @ResponseID)
SET @numberOfTags = (LEN(@inputString) - 
                 LEN(REPLACE(@inputString, @searchString, ''))) /
                 LEN(@searchString)

IF @numberOfTags = 1 
BEGIN
SET @info = (SELECT SUBSTRING(Response, CHARINDEX('<GlJournal>',Response) + 11,5) FROM SysproIntegration..ifmTransactionDetailResponse WHERE TransactionDetailResponseID = @ResponseID)
SET @Reference = (SELECT DISTINCT Reference FROM GenJournalDetail WHERE Journal = CAST(@info as DECIMAL(5,0)))
END
ELSE
BEGIN
SET @info = (SELECT SUBSTRING(Response, CHARINDEX('<GlJournal>',Response) + 69,5) FROM SysproIntegration..ifmTransactionDetailResponse WHERE TransactionDetailResponseID = @ResponseID)
SET @Reference = (SELECT DISTINCT Reference FROM GenJournalDetail WHERE Journal = CAST(@info as DECIMAL(5,0)))
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an int test you might adapt:

```
declare @xml xml, @tags smallint

SET @tags = 1

-- Load @xml...
--SELECT @xml = Response 
--FROM SysproIntegration..ifmTransactionDetailResponse 
--WHERE TransactionDetailResponseID = @ResponseID

-- ... or for test...
IF @tags = 1 BEGIN
    -- Test 1 GLJournal tag
    SET @xml = '12346'
END ELSE IF @tags = 2 BEGIN
    -- Test 2 GLJournal tags
    SET @xml = '
        
        
        12345
    '
END ELSE BEGIN
    -- Test no GLJournal tags 
    SET @xml = ''
END    

DECLARE @i int; SET @i = -1

-- Try one tag    
SELECT @i = ParamValues.ID.query('GLJournal').value('.','int')
FROM @xml.nodes('/') as ParamValues(ID)

IF @i = 0   
    -- Try two tags 
    SELECT @i = ParamValues.ID.query('GLJournal').value('.','int')
    FROM @xml.nodes('/GLJournal') as ParamValues(ID)     

SELECT @i    

-- INSERT INTO ZJournalRecords... other stuff
```